# Recursive Object Builder. Values are replacing previous values

Tags: c#, list, recursion

i am having trouble with my recursive fuction.

```
Collection.Add(RecursiveTreeBuilder(myList));

public TreeNodeItem RecursiveTreeBuilder(List<TestObject> pList)
    {
        if (pList == null)
            return null;

        TreeNodeItem _node = new TreeNodeItem();
        for (int x=0; x<pList.Count; x++)
        {
            _node.Header = pList[x].Name;
            _node.Children.Add(RecursiveTreeBuilder(pList[x].Children));
        }

        return _node;
    }
```

What the Fuction is supposed to do is return a single node that has a list of nodes inside that node based on the original list.

It works to the point where only the final node remains in each list.

Help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better answer using the .LINQ library.

```
public ObservableCollection<TreeNodeItem> TreeNodeBuilder(List<IMetaData> pList)
    {
        if (pList == null)
            return null;

        var items = pList
            .Select(e => new TreeNodeItem()
            {
                Header = e.Name,
                Tag = e.Tag.ToString(),
                Focusable = true,
                Children = TreeNodeBuilder(e.Children)
            });

        return new ObservableCollection<TreeNodeItem>(items);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Think about what you're doing when the fuction calls itself: You're passing in *all* of `pList[x]`'s children each time. What you want to do is pass in *one* `TestObject` to `RecursiveTreeBuilder`, which then creates a new tree node for that particular `TestObject`. Then for each single child of the `TestObject`, you want to create a child new tree node for that child and add it to the tree node.

You want a method that takes one `TestObject` and returns one `TreeNodeItem`. That's the general case anyhow, and also the easiest way to keep it straight. Your initial unparented `List<TestObject>` is the special case -- so write a different overload for that.

But even easier to keep straight, would be to store your list of `TestObject` as a single `TestObject` with the list in its children -- then you only need the one general-case version of the method.

```
//  Overload for single child TestObject
public TreeNodeItem RecursiveTreeBuilder(TestObject pList)
{
    TreeNodeItem node = new TreeNodeItem();
    node.Header = pList.Name;

    foreach (var child in pList.Children)
    {
        if (child != null)
        {
            node.Children.Add(RecursiveTreeBuilder(child));
        }
    }

    return node;
}

//  Your list method, with fixes
public TreeNodeItem RecursiveTreeBuilder(List<TestObject> pList, string rootHeader)
{
    if (pList == null)
        return null;

    TreeNodeItem rootNode = new TreeNodeItem();
    rootNode.Header = rootHeader;

    foreach (var obj in pList)
    {
        rootNode.Children.Add(RecursiveTreeBuilder(obj));
    }

    return rootNode;
}
```

Also, don't put an underscore prefix on a local variable name. By convention, the underscore prefix means the identifier is a private field belonging to the class.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. And thanks for the insight on local variable names. This is just a bad habit i built over time. slowly trying to get rid of it.